# Space complexity in memoized fibonacci code

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o, space-complexity

```
void allFib(int n) {
   int[] memo = new int[n + 1];
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
      System.out.println(i + ": "+ fib(i, memo));
   }
}

int fib(int n, int[] memo) {
   if (n <= 0) return 0;
   else if (n == 1) return 1;
   else if (memo[n] > 0) return memo[n];
   memo[n] = fib(n - 1, memo) + fib(n - 2, memo);
   return memo[n];
}
```

In the above memoized code to print the first n fibonacci numbers, what is the space complexity due to the recursive calls in the fib method (`memo[n]= fib(n - 1, memo) + fib(n - 2, memo);`)? Even though they look like recursive calls, all they really do is lookup memo[n - 1] and memo[n - 2] as those are guaranteed to have already been computed. But because they are in this form and set up their own stack in memory, should each of those calls have a memory footprint? If so, what?

If I were to replace that line with `memo[n] = memo[n - 1] + memo[n - 2]`, the space complexity contributed by THIS line would be reduced to O(1) right?

I know that the overall space complexity is at least O(n) because of the memo array of size n + 1.

Answer (score 2):

The extra space complexity is `O(1)` even with recursive calls when you compute sequential Fibonacci numbers from the smallest to the largest one.

Indeed, each new call to `fib` in the loop results in exactly two calls (well, except for `i = 0` and `i = 1`, where no additional calls are made). 
Each call requires a constant amount of space. The depth of recursion is bounded by 2, so the total extra amount of space required is constant.

If you replaced it with a loop with summation `memo[n] = memo[n - 1] + memo[n - 2]`, the extra space complexity would stay `O(1)`, so it would not be reduced.